# comparing the means of multiple distributions

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, bonferroni

I wish to compare the means of three independent data sets.  These are exam scores that are from class A and class B and class C.  Class A and B are normal and tested ok for homogeneity.  A T-Test between class A and B revealed that the sets are significantly different and looking at the mean and median, and I determined class A performed better than B (examining the means).  When comparing the means between A and C and then B and C using the Mann Whitney U test, the both scenarios didn't show significance.  I thought that the comparison between A and C would test significant being b/c of the results of the T-Test.

I recently learned that when doing a multiple amount of comparisons, I have to apply the Bonferroni correction to my p value (p => .05/3 => .0167).  When comparing the means of A/B, B/C and A/C using p = .0167 all of the result comparison showed no significance.  My question is,..when I write my results, should I determine there was no significant relationship found between the settings.  That is to say, it wasn't found class A, B and C performed alike?
I don't think I should ignore the T Test result b/c a parametric test is always better.  What do you think?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  My original type up had an error.  After the T Test with A and B, I meant to say "and I determined class A performed better than B" looking at their means.  Sorry about the error.  The mean of set A scores is 74.72.  The mean of B is 62.66, and then C mean is 66.03.  I never thought to try the Kruskal-Wallis test on all three.  I will do this later on today and post the results.  I first have to do some research on what that test is about.  This is all new to me.  Again, thanks for your input.  :)

Comment: Previous comment and response to your Comment moved to Answer format.

Answer (score 1):

Moving yesterday's comments to Answer format to avoid abbreviations and make
room for some illustrations:

It seems you're saying that the sample means are arranged $\bar X_A>\bar X_C>\bar X_B.$ Using a t test, you have found a significant difference between groups A an B with a t test. But using nonparametric tests, you did not find significant differences not between A and C or between C and B.

It may be annoying not to know the exact pattern of differences, but it is not unusual that one is not able to resolve the exact pattern.

I hope you can try a Kruskal-Wallis test on data for all three groups. It may show not all equal, but ad hoc rank-based two-sample tests may still not resolve whether C differs form A or from B.

Also, the rank-based tests (Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon and Kruskal-Wallis) may give different results from t tests and standard ANOVAs. They use different criteria. For normal data, t tests and standard ANOVA are more powerful (more likely to find true differences), but they are different tests using different criteria. Especially for non-normal data, the rank based tests may find significant differences where the normal-based t tests and ANOVA do not.

**Addendum** (in response to Comment):

Thanks for the clarifications and additional detail. Roughly speaking, the Kruskal-Wallis test is a generalization of the two-sample Wilcoxon rank sum (equivalent to Mann-Whitney U) to handle $k$ groups--just as a one-way ANOVA is a generalization of the pooled 2-sample t test to handle $k$ groups.

I am not sure what you see in group C to prevent your doing one-way ANOVA. In case you fear unequal variances, there is a Welch version of one one-way ANOVA that doesn't require variances to be equal.

---

Here are simulated data somewhat similar to yours, which I use to illustrate some
procedures in R statistical software.

```
set.seed(718)  # retain 'set.seed' for exactly same fake data; omit for fresh dataset
A = rnorm(30, 70, 15);  B = rnorm(30, 65, 15);  C = rnorm(30, 67, 15)
Scores = c(A, B, C);  Classes = as.factor(rep(1:3, each=30))  # 'as.factor' crucial
boxplot(Scores ~ Classes, col="skyblue2", pch=20)

mean(A); mean(B); mean(C)
[1] 69.70417
[1] 60.35609
[1] 64.89248
```

[image]

A one-way ANOVA finds differences:

```
anova.out = aov(Scores ~ Classes)
summary(anova.out)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
Classes      2   1214   607.0     3.3 0.0415 *
Residuals   87  16002   183.9                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

A comparison of A with B is almost significant, but C is not significantly
different from either A or B. (A rather conservative Bonferroni adjustment ensures that
the family of comparisons has an error rate below 5%.) 
[See [*this demo*](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~martin/W2024/R3.pdf) for a discussion on the procedure so far.]
A t test comparing A and B, not
shown, has P-value about 0.02.

```
pairwise.t.test(Scores, Classes, p.adj="bonf")

        Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 

data:  Scores and Classes 

  1     2    
2 0.056 -    
3 0.663 0.745
```

A Kruskal-Wallis test shows differences in medians.

```
        Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  Scores by Classes
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 6.3386, df = 2, p-value = 0.04203
```

A 2-sample Wilcoxon test finds a significant difference between A and B.

```
wilcox.test(A,B)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  A and B
W = 597, p-value = 0.02959
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Wilcoxon tests, not shown, find a significant difference between A and C, but not
between B and C. (The accumulated error rate looking at several Wilcoxon tests is not controlled.)

Comment: I just realized I failed to say in the post that C is not normal so the Welch version of one-way ANOVA cant be used. Thx for sharing that test b/c I never heard of it.  I ran the Kruskal Wallis and it showed no difference in the distribution of populations.  The Ad Hoc found a sign diff between A/B, not for A/C or B/C (just what you found :)) Should I concluded my results and say there was a sign found using the T-Test comparing the means of A and B but no evidence pointed significant difference in the means of A/C and B/C as per the Kruskal-Wallis test.

Comment: That sounds appropriate. Maybe something like "The mean of C is intermediate btw A and B, so it is reasonable to believe the pop mean of C is intermediate. However, significant difference from neither A or B could be established."

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.  Last questions, do you think the significance between A/B and A/C wasn't found b/c of the sample size which was A (n=18) ; B (n=43) and C (n=27)?  Any thoughts on why this could have happened.

Comment: When sample sizes are small and variances are large it frequently happens that the overall test, ANOVA or Kruskal-Wallis, detects that there are "some differences." That is, not all pop means (or medians) are equal. BUT, there may not be enough info to detect the actual pattern of those differences. About all that can be said for sure is that the most extreme two must obviously differ because we have evidence that "some" differences are present. // A power study before doing an expt, with good guesses at the pop SDs can help to know sample sizes needed to resolve patterns of differences.

Comment: Thank you thank you!  I really learned a lot from you.  I am grateful.  Have a good night:)